# How to print this to the console?

Tags: javascript

I'm recently learning (for a few days) how to work with javascript.

```
var counter = 10;
var returnedValue = counter--; counter--; counter-- ;
console.log ( counter );
console.log ( returnedValue );
```

Anyway on this exercise I have to start with a value of 10, reduce to 7 using unary operators and then print both values.

> Here is the description of the exercise:

> Initialize a variable called counter with the value 10 and print it to the console.

> Using unary operators, decrement the value in the variable until you reach the number 7.

> Print the final value.

However the platform where I am learning gives me the following error:

"Don't forget to print the variable to the console before and after the decrementations"

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not printing the initial value *before* the decrementing statements.

Comment: Also what's the point of the `returnedValue` variable? The exercise did not ask for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your JavaScript is valid, the instructions are telling you to print the value both *before* and *after* doing the decrements.

I'm not sure if your platform has taught you about loops yet, but here's a solution:

```
var counter = 10;
console.log ( counter ); //printing before here
while (counter > 7) {
  counter--; //decrement
} //you could also just do counter--; counter--; counter--; like you had before
console.log ( counter ); //printing after
```

The instructions also say "decrement the value in the variable" which I'm taking to mean "don't create a new variable -- decrement the counter in place"

Comment: Thanks, but the platform wanted:

var counter = 10;
console.log ( counter ); //printing before here
var returnedValue = counter--; counter--; counter--;
console.log ( counter ); //printing after

Answer (score 0):

You are print the modificated value before the original value.

So, you need flipp print order:

```js
var counter = 10;
var returnedValue = counter--; counter--; counter-- ;
console.log ( returnedValue );
console.log ( counter );
```